# Using AAD APP for authentication is deprecated... is my point correct

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am following the steps mentioned on this link @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread to register a new application inside Azure AD. but when i click to register a new application inside my Azure account, i got this message:-

[image]

so does this mean that Azure AD App-Only as a method of authentication is now deprecated ? if the answer is yes then what is the most up to date approach?
now what i am trying to do is to register an application inside Azure AD and create a certificate then use the clientId,TenantId, certificate to be able to authenticate my SharePoint CSOM code against SharePoint online using this code `PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager(clientId, certificatePath, certificatePassword, tenantId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification talks about two authentication libraries, ADAL and MSAL. ADAL is deprecated.

In your case, you are using another layer of abstraction on top - [PnP Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework). If you look closely at the [sources](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/dev/src/lib/PnP.Framework/PnP.Framework.csproj#L220) of PnP Framework, you will see this Nuget reference:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.30.1" />
```

This is [MSAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/). So the code in your question is fine, and you can use it without worries. Nothing about this authentication method is deprecated.

Comment: @johnGu glad I could help. If you consider your question solved, I would appreciate if you accept my answer. Otherwise feel free to ask for further information if you think anything is missing.

Answer (score 1):

•   The Azure AD App-only authentication method is not deprecated, instead the authentication libraries have been updated in it to include standard authentication methods compliant with OAuthv2.0 and Open ID Connect. The method of registering an app in Azure AD as followed by you by referring the documentation link suggests you to use a certificate to request access and grant permission to the app using the private key to that certificate.

•   As in the method of setting up an Azure AD app-only access, the application acquires a token by using certificate credentials and then uses the token to make requests of the resource, thus this method of authentication flow is one of the several methods that are supported by the updated MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) as these client credentials need to be registered with Azure AD and passed in when constructing the confidential client application object in your code. Therefore, as this method of authentication flow is supported in MSAL, it is not deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Please find the below link for more information on your query: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows

Thanking you,

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but can you provide a code sample on how to do the authentication using non-deprecated approach?

Comment: You are welcome, you can refer this link for referring more details on the code samples for your query. Link : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials